# Tensorflow Object Detection API not detecting objects

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I've trained my custom sign language dataset on Colab. It works just fine, It can also detect objects. Then I've downloaded the content folder on colab to transfer it on jupyter notebook. I've used the same process from my colab notebook. But on jupyter notebook, it can't detect objects, there's no bounding boxes as well. It's just a plain image.

Here's the code:

```
filenames = list(pathlib.Path('D:/Conda/sample_project/models/content/training/').glob('*.index'))

filenames.sort()
print(filenames)

pipeline_file = 'D:/Conda/sample_project/models/content/models/research/deploy/pipeline_file.config'
#recover our saved model
pipeline_config = pipeline_file
#generally you want to put the last ckpt from training in here
model_dir = str(filenames[-1]).replace('.index','')
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(
      model_config=model_config, is_training=False)


detect_fn = get_model_detection_function(detection_model)


#map labels for inference decoding
label_map_path = configs['eval_input_config'].label_map_path
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(label_map_path)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(
    label_map,
    max_num_classes=label_map_util.get_max_label_map_index(label_map),
    use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map, use_display_name=True)

#run detector on test image
#it takes a little longer on the first run and then runs at normal speed.
import random

TEST_IMAGE_PATHS = glob.glob('C:/Users/moon/Downloads/Compressed/American Sign Language Letters.v1-v1.multiclass/train/*.jpg')
image_path = random.choice(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS)
image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image_path)



# Things to try:
# Flip horizontally
# image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

# Convert image to grayscale
# image_np = np.tile(
#     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np_with_detections,
      detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
      (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
      detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      max_boxes_to_draw=200,
      min_score_thresh=.5,
      agnostic_mode=False,
)
my_classes = detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset
my_scores = detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy()

min_score = 0.5

print([category_index[value]['name']
        for index,value in enumerate(my_classes)
        if my_scores[index] > min_score
     ])


plt.figure(figsize=(12,16))
plt.imshow(image_np_with_detections)
plt.show()
```

I don't know what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

When we your facing where the code run Successfully in Google Colab but not in Jupyter Notebook it could be due to some reasons.

> Kindly check the file paths what your using in your Jupyter Notebook are correct and accessible from your local machine. Sometimes can differ between Colab and local machine.

> Check model is loading correctly in Jupyter Notebook. We can use below command:

```
    print("Model Directory:", model_dir)
```

> Need to check `model_builder.build()` functions is constructing the detection model correctly or not by using this below command.

```
    print("Model Config:", model_config)
```

> Please verify the image is loaded or not correctly into `image_np` by using this below command.

```
    print("Image Shape:", image_np.shape)
```

Kindly follow this steps to resolve the issue.